# Windows logs UPN not present

Tags: windows, active-directory, logging

Client - windows 10
AD - windows 2008R2
In log events universal principal names ARE NOT present.
Usernames are only given in the Down-Level Logon Name format.
Why is that and what's the way to force the logging subsystem to specify UPNs in log events?

Answer (score 2):

You don't.

The UPN is a location feature used to identify the domain and samAccountName. After that, its as if domain\samAccountName was used.  The purpose of the UPN is to make the user logon experience easier and more consistent, particularly in large environments with multiple forests/domains, and for scenarios where objects are moved or domains are collapsed/reduced.

Unlike samAccountName, it's possible to configure Active Directory to not enforce uniqueness constraints for the userPrincipalName attribute with a domain, and uniqueness constraints for userPrincipalName across domains are never enforced. An attribute that may not uniquely identify an object is not an appropriate attribute for security auditing events.

Comment: https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventID=4648 seems to disagree with you. Please have a look at the sample event

Comment: @Antuan: that link says nothing about userPrincipalName. I just logged on to a computer, and the 4648 event had the samAccountName in it.

Comment: I'm not doubting the fact that on your computer there's no UPN for your 4648 event. I don't see a UPN in my configuration either. If you at the provided link more closely, the UPN IS present in the example section under "Account Whose Credentials Were Used:".